# Wheel Centricity - Barrel

Tags: wheels

I have a quick question in regards to a specification I saw concerning wheels. Specifically, the property that left me perplex is that of "centricity". The specifications of the wheels mentioned that the "centricity" of the wheels are "barrel". The wheel specifications that mention this are the following:

https://www.canadiantire.ca/en/wheels/pdp/steel-rim-wheel-black-0096295p.0095929.html

Otherwise, I saw a post here explaining what the "barrel" is:

https://www.autogeekonline.net/forum/auto-detailing-101-a/60542-what-barrel-wheel.html

I understood what the barrel of a wheel is, the only thing I am wondering is if the wheel centricity of "barrel" means that the wheels are, what is commonly known as, "hub centric"? I am a bit perplexed since the barrel of a wheel and the hub of the wheel are different parts, but, do they center the wheel in the same manner or are they two different wheel centering methods?

Thanks in advance to the ones who reply.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe the difference is what is centering the wheel. Does the wheel use the hub or the barrell to center it on the axle. Even for the barrel, I believe it uses the lugs and the lug nuts to center it onto the axle. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you may be right since entering the wheel on the axle using only the barrel of the wheel as the reference must be somewhat a complicated task. I might be wrong as well. Anyhow, thanks again for trying to help out.